# Повторное выполнение запроса занимает времени на несколько порядков больше

Tags: sql, oracle

При первом выполнении запроса тратится меньше секунды времени.
При повторном выполнении меняем один входной параметр и выполнение идёт уже 11 минут.

Насколько понимаю,причина в том, что при повторном выполнении используется уже сформированный план запроса, который не оптимален для следующего запроса.

Есть ли настройка, позволяющая не сохранять план конкретного запроса, или же сбрасывать его сразу же после выполнения запроса?
alter system flush shared_pool; - не вариант

[Сам запрос](https://dropmefiles.com/h6X4I) . Оракл 11

Запрос отрабатывает за 11 минут когда меняем :ValueDate и запускаем повторно.

Comment: `входной параметр` - в виде `bind variable`? Речь идет о SELECT или вызове функции/процедуры?

Comment: да, входной параметр bind variable. Речь о SELECT запросе

Comment: Какая версия Oracle DB? Как распределены данные в столбце (по которому идет фильтрация) - имеет ли место `data skewness`? Как именно используется `bind variable` - приведите соответствующую часть кода

Comment: Добавил сам запрос и то, что Вы спрашивали в описание вопроса

Comment: Возможно глупый вопрос, но не зависит ли это от значения параметра. Что произойдет если поменять значения местами?

Comment: нет, от значения не зависит. Если мы сразу зададим значение сразу ValueDate сразу, как во второй попытке, то запрос отработает быстро.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что ссылка больше не работает, а в самом вопросе недостаточно информации.